# Configure Chrome options for Cypress

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing

In Selenium projects, I'm used to configure the Chrome options. Is there a way of doing it in Cypress projects?

I need to test a website that is flagged like "unsafe" because of its obsolete certificates, and I need to bypass the "Unprotected connection" window.

What it looks like in Selenium projects:

```
DesiredCapabilities handlSSLErr = DesiredCapabilities.chrome ()       
handlSSLErr.setCapability (CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true)
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver (handlSSLErr);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Setting `chromeWebSecurity` to false will help or not?

Comment: Nope. That's too bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling my antivirus fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As per the documentation on cypress , you need to add below in your cypress.json file for achieving the same :

{
"chromeWebSecurity": false
}

Please check below link for more detailed info [Here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/web-security.html#Set-chromeWebSecurity-to-false)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it is not sufficient and I still have the error message.

Comment: I guess if antivirus was the problem , your site shouldn't open on normal browser too. Was it opening there ??

Comment: Yes @Karan :) that's why I was so puzzled!

Comment: ohkay..glad you found the solution.